# IDM integration in chrome is not functioning

Tags: google-chrome, installation, google-chrome-extensions, context-menu

I am using the latest versions of both IDM and Chrome, but IDM context menu is greyed out. I tried reinstalling both Chrome and IDM, but found the following error -

*Warning note: advanced browser integration is disabled in IDM, or IDM update is required*
[Post Installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v65ax.png)

But Advanced Integration is enabled in IDM, and both Chrome and IDM are up to date.
[Advanced Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etRIL.png)

How can I get IDM working again ?

Answer (score -1):

firsty delete the extention from chrome
and after theat go to advance setting and click on reset setting
after resetting install idm extention manualy
(1)open extention tab in chrome
(2)go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager and select IDMGCExt.crx
and drop into extention tab in chrome
this will install this extenstion in chrome
100% work